Hugo / Nebula Award Winning Short Story about a young man enslaved on Ganymede
I read an inspirational sci fi short story about a young man who is enslaved to collect water on Ganymede, where everyone is burnished by the sun to a dark golden brown color and wears loincloths.  The hero eventually stages revolt against the super powerful overlords.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How do you specifically recall it was an award-winning story?  Did you read it in an anthology of award-winning stories?  When did you read it?

I read it in a compilation of Hugo/Nebula Winner short stories from one of the libraries around here.  I have searched for it there but to no avail...

That...doesn't sound like a Hugo or Nebula winner.  No one has considered Ganymede habitable since probably the 1930s. Unless this was written since about 1990 when I stopped keeping track, I can pretty much guarantee you it wasn't such a winner.

Switch out Ganymede for Venus, and maybe Heinlein's Logic of Empire? (RAH's Farmer In The Sky is set on Ganymede, but otherwise doesn't fit)

Were the overlords human beings or space aliens?

Collect water? In what way?  This is a primitive society where they draw the water from wells, no running water?

Good questions:  The overlords were humans as far as I know, but I don't recall the author bringing their physical appearance into play.  In terms water collection, I am unsure honestly.  I know they barely wore any clothes and had zero resources for themselves.  Also the overlords would roll up above them in a ship.  The boy makes history as the hero who starts the revolt and somehow stops up the ship.  I got the impression this was not a stand alone story, but had a book or two connected, so thats why I am looking.  Very good guesses tho about Heinlin and Farmer in the Sky

In terms of Ganymede's habitability, I would agree that makes no sense.  I just recall the name.   I think the commenter here gives a bit too much credit to the authors and selectors of the Hugo awards for knowing real science.
